# SUMIFS formula to present SUM per month

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I had some help recently with using SUMIFS to pull data within data from a large table and present it in a new table. However i've hit a wall with trying to apply an appropriate formula.

My source table features all sales of individual items, and includes the date of the order.

My presentation table will feature number of certain item sold per month.

My source date is the actual date of sale, but formatted as (mmmm) so it reads as the month.

My reference date for my presentation table is the 1st of each month, but again formatted as (mmmm) so it reads the same as my source.

The formula i've managed to come up with is as follows:

```
=SUMIFS('All Sales'!J2:J1907,  'All Sales'!A2:A1907,  "<="&EOMONTH('Sales by Pump'!B14, 0),  'All Sales'!H2:I1907,"="& 'Sales by Pump'!A16)
```

I am getting a #VALUE error so obviously either the formula is not suitable for what i want or i'm asking the wrong questions with it.

An example of my data is below (source on the left, presentation on the right), but of course you can tell by my formula that it's a little bit more expansive.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to insert a column between Date and Item and put formula in (assuming date is Column B) and define also column names in the sum table with the same formula.
`=text($C2,"mmm")`
then your sumifs would look like (based on columns showed in your question"
`=SUMIFS($E$2:$E$2000,$C$2:$C$2000,"H$1",$D$2:$D$2000,"$G2")`

Of course you can reference other sheets if data is elsewhere.  Make sure you keep criteria in quotes, and no need to comparison characters <>=

Answer (score 0):

Because of the confusion to me of your columns, I made your data into a **Table** and used structured references (*you can change this to regular addressing if you prefer*).

The formula assumes that, as I interpreted what you wrote, all "Months" are real dates formatted to `mmm`; and the dates in row 1 of your presentation table are also real dates referring to the beginning of the month.

Formula (fill across and down as needed):

```
H2: =SUMIFS(orderTbl[[Qty]:[Qty]],orderTbl[[Date]:[Date]],">="&H$1,orderTbl[[Date]:[Date]],"<="&EOMONTH(H$1,0),orderTbl[[Item]:[Item]],$G2)
```

**Data**

[image]

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Yes, so my order dates are, for example, 13/01/2020, 28/01/2020 etc but formatted as (mmmm) so read as (January), and my presentation dates are 01/01/2020 formatted as (mmmm) to read (January) also. I did this only because i assumed it helps the formula find what i want more easily, but if that's unnecessary i'm happy to adjust.

Comment: @hydrojack formatting does not matter so long as they are all real dates. The formula I provided should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$13=$F2)*(TEXT(TEXT($B$2:$B$13,"mmm"),0)=G$1)*$D$2:$D$13)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Works wonders on my sample page, but when i apply it to my actual charts it gives me a Value Not Available error. I'm wondering if my date formats are wrong, or if referencing another sheet is upsetting it...

Comment: Solved my error, however now my results show 0. Which i've figured out is because my Presentation table also uses an actual date formatted by "mmm". I need this as my sales range across multiple years, so just referencing "Jan" pulls both 2020 and 2021, for example.